# This SearchView icon like in Google Play, is it default or customized？

Tags: android, searchview

I want to know how to get this SearchView icon like in Google Play (three horizontal lines become an arrow),  is it default or customized？

I found some open source controls, like Floating Search View (https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview), but I haven’t found that icon.

[three horizontal lines become an arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK747.gif)

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/

See this package has class [`SearchEditTextLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-n-preview-4/src/com/android/dialer/widget/SearchEditTextLayout.java).

This class is written by google.

BTW if you don't want dive in this code, you can use

- https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView
- https://github.com/KieronQuinn/PersistentSearch